# Have I got the right understanding of the mu operator?

Tags: terminology, computability, mu-calculus

I have a homework problem that says:

***For $g(x,y)=xy-5$ compute $h(x) = \mu y(g(x,y))$ and determine its domain.***

I was under the impression that this means the least y such that $g(x,y)=0$, so then $y = \frac{5}{x}, D=\{x \in \mathbb{N}, x \neq 0\}$

So $h(x)=\frac{5}{x}$?

Comment: Is this a computer-science problem?

Comment: I'm studying it as part of a unit on primitive recursion, so ... yes

Comment: The context has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: $\mu y.\ \chi(y)$ usually means the least $y$ such that $\chi(y)$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $h(x)$ is always a non-negative integer (whenever it's defined).

As a side note, usually primitive recursive functions are assumed to be non-negative, and so $\max(xy-5,0)$ is more usual than what you wrote.